# Replace SSIS with PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, ssis

Some people don't like SSIS for the following reasons,

1. Need to find and click the express replacement scattered in different place when design a little bit more complex package.
2. These merge, lookup components don't perform well. I heard a lot of consultants just recommend loading data in the SQL Server tables and use transact-sql.

I've used a powershell in a small project which export the data and create csv files. I've used powershell and like it. Is it a trend to replace some of the tasks traditionally using SSIS with Powershell? Especially in the export only cases?

Comment: "Is it a trend" is subjective and doesn't have a definitive answer.

Comment: @AndyArismendi "trend" can be measured by statistical significance level. It's not that subjective.

Answer (score 7):

For very small projects/tasks power shell is an ok tool.

For projects that need to be robust, maintainable, modular, handle errors and auditing, SSIS is vastly superior.

The truth is, too many SSIS implementations are crafted by devs that don't understand the strengths of the program. They simply try to replicate their current T-SQL ETL process into SSIS with minimal effort or leverage of its capabilities. Performance issues almost always go right along with this.

SSIS is Not just a GUI way to get SPs and TSQL to autorun. If you really want to learn more on the subject I suggest picking up a few books - careful listening to narrow-fielded experts; their skillsets can easily fade from relevance and keep others behind with them.

Powershell trend away from SSIS? Not anywhere close to where it counts.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old topic but I find it is well worth discussing. So I'd like to put a few ideas why I think SSIS is a bad choice 99% of the time as a ETL tool.

At this time, the only thing I can think of SSIS better than PowerShell is its performance in handling huge amount of data with multiple sources / targets, this is mainly due to the SSIS internal parallelism and caching capability.

However, SSIS is notorious for its error message, almost unable to debug once SSIS packages are deployed, also from source control perspective, SSIS packages, which are XML files, are difficult to compare between versions, also very fragile once either source or target objects have minor changes (like a column on target is increased by one char).

In my prod environment, there are many SSIS packages deployed and scheduled with sql agent jobs, so when there is a job failure, there is no way for me to figure out the problem until I went to TFS to find the SSIS project and open it in Visual Studio to figure out the logic. It is a nightmare.

With PowerShell, the code you see is the code executed, and you can always get the logic from the PS code and do the trouble-shooting along the way.

With many, many open-sourced PS modules these days, PowerShell's power is increasing exponentially, it is indeed the time to consider using PS as an alternative tool rather than the SSIS.